# SQL - Find Unique values within grouped results

Tags: sql

I have the following tables

```
**Order**
- Id (int)
- OrderDate (datetime)
- OrderNumber (nvarchar)
- CustomerId (int)
- TotalAmount (decimal)
```

```
**OrderItem**
- Id (int)
- OrderId (int)
- ProductId (int)
- UnitPrice (decimal)
- Quantity (int)
```

```
**Product**
- Id (int)
- ProductName (nvarchar)
- SupplierId (int)
- UnitPrice (decimal)
- Package (nvarchar)
- IsDiscontinued (bit)
```

```
**Supplier**
- Id (int)
- CompanyName (nvarchar)
- ContactName (nvarchar)
- ContactTitle (nvarchar)
- City (nvarchar)
- Country (nvarchar)
- Phone (nvarchar)
- Fax (nvarchar)
```

I need to Find out all the orders which contains products which are supplied from single country. Any help appreciated.

Comment: can you please make a sqlfiddle

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Have joined the query as below

select [o].id as [OrderID], [O].CustomerID as [CustomerID], 
[Oi].Orderid as [OIOrderID], OI.ProductID, P.ProductName, P.ID AS [ProductIDa], P.IsDiscontinued,
s.city, s.country
from [order] o 
inner join [orderitem] oi on o.id = oi.orderid
inner join [product] p on oi.productid = p.id  
inner join [supplier] s on p.supplierid = s.id

Sample DB: http://www.dofactory.com/sql/sandbox

Comment: If you have additional information then **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one it may help

```
    select * from (
        select * from (
            select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by s.Country order by s.Country) RowNo,o.* from [order] as o
            inner join OrderItem as oi on o.Id = oi.OrderId 
            inner join Product as p on ProductId = p.Id
            inner join Supplier as s on p.SupplierId = s.Id
        ) as t 
        where RowNo > 1
    ) as t
    right join [order] as o on t.Id = o.Id
    where t.Id is null
```